# Is there any way to change an Azure Active Directory application's display photo using PowerShell?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I have a script which (among many other things) creates a service principal in our corp AAD instance. Since I've collected a good number of service principals during my time here, it would be nice to distinguish them visually using a photo. Is there any way to do this via script? I've found [Set-AzureADUserThumbnailPhoto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/Set-AzureADUserThumbnailPhoto?view=azureadps-2.0) but it doesn't seem to work for AAD applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`Set-AzureADApplicationLogo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadapplicationlogo?view=azureadps-2.0), when you use it set the logo of the AD App(app registration), its service principal(enterprise application) logo will also change.

```
Set-AzureADApplicationLogo -ObjectId <app-objectid> -FilePath C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\pic.jpg
```

[image]

[image]